# ¿Es posible eliminar las celdas en blanco y recorrer los datos de una columna en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Cuento con un archivo en Excel en donde tengo una columna en específico que tiene celdas en blanco. El detalle es que quiero eliminar esos espacios en blanco y recorrer los datos, utilizando algunos comandos en Excel si se puede. El detalle es que yo lo debo hacer con Pandas (Python).

El código que implementé es el siguiente:

```
# Importar librerias
import pandas as pd

# Lectura del archivo
df = pd.read_excel("ejemplo.xlsx") #index_col = 0 
#print(df)

# Eliminar filas en blanco
clase = df.dropna(axis='columns')
print(clase)

# Exportar archivo formato excel 
#clase.to_excel('ejemplo_exportado.xlsx', index = False) 
#resultado.info()
```

solo que esta implementación de código me borra la mayoría de los datos que necesito, y no me sirve.

El archivo en Excel que tengo es el siguiente:

[image: ejemplo]

y el resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Es muy fácil, puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) con [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Utilizando los datos de tu pregunta (Por cierto, para la próxima pregunta utiliza texto para mostrar tus datos en lugar de imágenes, de esa forma los podemos copiar y pegar en lugar de reescribirlos) en un archivo "Prueba.xlsx" tengo el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    País        Capital         Nombre de la persona
0   México      México          Carlos
1   NaN         NaN             NaN
2   NaN         Madrid          Sergio
3   España      NaN             NaN
4   NaN         Washington      George
5   NaN         NaN             NaN
6   EUA         NaN             NaN
7   NaN         NaN             NaN
8   Argentina   Buenos Aires    Lautaro
9   NaN         NaN             NaN
10  NaN         NaN             NaN
11  Uruguay     Montevideo      Luis
```

**Nota:** País y México llevan acento.

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Prueba.xlsx')
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
df
```

Esto recorre todas las celdas con valores hacia arriba y genera el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    País        Capital         Nombre de la persona
0   México      México          Carlos
1   España      Madrid          Sergio
2   EUA         Washington      George
3   Argentina   Buenos Aires    Lautaro
4   Uruguay     Montevideo      Luis
```